# What does it mean when a capacitor and it's connectors are marked with a red marker?

Tags: capacitor, markings

Is there some kind of convention in electrical component maintenance that would explain a red marking on a capacitor?

I found this in my Pioneer SA 5300 audio amplifier and wondered if this carried some special meaning.

[image: Pioneer marked capacitor connectors]

Comment: It looks like QC marks to me.  Someone in the QA department saying "Yes, I looked at that well enough to stake my next performance review on the statistical likeliness of this particular part failing."

Comment: Seems more like a high voltage notifying or test point marks to me.

Comment: There is no way to know without asking the assembler

Comment: @Ghedipunk if you could make that an answer I will accept it. Thanks!

Comment: the two solder joints below the three red marks look like they may be bad (cracked) .... give them a closer look

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely Quality Assurance inspection.
For what purpose is anyone's guess (comments above are good guesses)....
Here are some other ideas:

- Such a large part as this could cause problems at or before the
  wave-soldering stage....an inspection to see that it is well-seated
  against the PCB after soldering.
- A three-legged part with fat leads may miss a hole.
  An inspection to see that all three made it through their respective
  holes and bend over to make an acceptable mechanical seat.
- An inspection to ensure that a polarized capacitor was inserted the
  right way, to save injury to the QA-person down the line who
  powers-it-up the first time.